# I have Velocity transformer issue as I have been Migrating from mule 2.2.1 to Mule 3.3.2

Tags: java, spring, mule

Hi and thank you for your help in advance.
I am trying to migrate app from Mule 2.2.1 to Standalone Mule.
Mule 2.2.1 is embeded into tomcat. Original Velocity transformer with Mule 2.2.1 works ok, but as I start using standalone Mule 3.3.2 it does not.
This is my mule-config file fragment:

```
<spring:bean class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="velocityProperties">
            <spring:map>
                <spring:entry key="resource.loader" value="class"/>
                <spring:entry key="class.resource.loader.class" value="org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader"/>
            </spring:map>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
```

As I am starting mule, I get error:

```
Caused by: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to lookup beans of type interface org.mule.api.transformer.Converter from the Spring registry
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.internalLookupByType(SpringRegistry.java:184)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.lookupByType(SpringRegistry.java:171)
        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.lookupByType(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:160)
        at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupByType(MuleRegistryHelper.java:704)
        at org.mule.config.bootstrap.SimpleRegistryBootstrap.registerTransformers(SimpleRegistryBootstrap.java:322)
        at org.mule.config.bootstrap.SimpleRegistryBootstrap.initialise(SimpleRegistryBootstrap.java:185)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean#0' defined in URL [fi
rror: org/apache/velocity/exception/VelocityException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:767)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:698)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:319)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:396)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1164)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.internalLookupByType(SpringRegistry.java:178)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/exception/VelocityException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
```

I have these dependency for Spring

```
<dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

spring-version is 3.3.1

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It could be a class loader issue.

declare the **loader.override=org.springframework.ui.velocity** In mule-deploy.properties file and try (suggested in **https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/2587/sending_an_email_using_velocity_templates-2ke02.html**).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.You are right, but in addition to that I had to add 2 jars to %MULEHOME%/lib/user directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding velocity dependency to your pom -

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply.

The problem I was experiencing was not because of the dependency.
Actually it was there.

**Solution was to add 2 velocity jars: velocity and velocity-tools to** `%MULE_HOME%/lib/user.`
That solved the problem.
All specific Jars that needed for the Mule to get done something special, like transformation or JMS requires jars that should be added to the  `%MULE_HOME%/lib/user` directory